# copy Multiple values from multiple input fields into multiple input fields using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I can copy multiple input fields into other input fields, but I think it can be better.
Now I'm using the following code, but there has to be a better code.
Please help me out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#property_year_built").change(function() {
    $("#bouwjaar_field").val($('#property_year_built').val());
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#property_zip").change(function() {
    $("#postcode_field").val($('#property_zip').val());
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#property_price").change(function() {
    $("#koopprijs_field").val($('#property_price').val());
  });
});
```

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you do not need optimization here, at least not yet, just put them in single ready event

Comment: I'm not familiair with jQuery, can you please give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some css class to all you inputs that you would like to monitor "SomeCssClassOnAllTxt" in my example. Also add new attribute to all your 6 inputs in my case it is "someAttribute". Type the same attribute value to "#property_year_built" and "#bouwjaar_field" inputs. And make the same changes for other inputs...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".SomeCssClassOnAllTxt").change(function() {
      var attributeValue = $(this).attr('someAttribute');
      $("[someAttribute='+attributeValue+']")
                      .not(".SomeCssClassOnAllTxt")
                      .val($(this).val());
   });
});
```

**UPDATED:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#property_year_built").change(function() {
       $("#bouwjaar_field").val($('#property_year_built').val());
    });
    $("#property_zip").change(function() {
       $("#postcode_field").val($('#property_zip').val());
    });
    $("#property_price").change(function() {
       $("#koopprijs_field").val($('#property_price').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using WordPress and I cannot add CSS to the fields.

Comment: Ok, in this case I can see just one possible improvement, just keep one $(document).ready(function() {}); and copy inside three of you code pieces. Updated my answer.